# how to setup built-in webserver in PhpStorm

Tags: localhost, wamp, phpstorm

Set up:

1) OS - Win 8.1 
2) WAMP
3) PhpStorm 7.1.3

I have been working on Dreamweaver for quite a long time and recently I ditched it because of its limited features. Setting up a local env using Dreamweaver is fairly simple and I had no problem with it. So I installed PhpStorm thinking it would quite easy to run my PHP web app in the same way when I was using DW, but When I try to run my web app in PhpStorm using its built-in webserver I get `502 Bad Gateway` error, What I did is simply import the folder (which is in www directory) in PhpStorm and try to run it on browser, but I couldn't get it to work locally. I believe I have to set up Interpreter under settings, but how do I go ahead and what should I include?

When I run my webapp using WAMP the URL looks like

```
http://localhost/appname/trunk/public/
```

When I run it using PhpStorm built-in webserver the URL looks like

```
http://localhost:63342/appname/trunk/public/
```

Error: 502 bad gateway.

I am quite stuck now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's possibly related to not having php5-cgi or fastcgi installed. There are no catch-all solutions, but one person reported that installed fastcgi and reinstalling apache did the trick.

Comment: Q is: why do you need PhpStorm's own simple web server when you have complete and powerful Apache (as part of WAMP) there? And yes -- quite likely you need another PHP distro -- try non-thread safe one from PHP site instead of thread safe one that comes with WAMP.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First (check your interpreter)

1- From File choose Setting

2- In setting navigate to PHP

3- In Interpreter (if you don't have interpreter you will see message like that )

[image]

Second (Add new interpreter)

1-Add new interpreter From Add sign (green plus +) --> choose (other)local if you work in your local pc

2-write any name you want refer to (default PHP)

3- navigate to your PHP directory file From PHP home*

I hope this help you

[image]

*If you use wamp you will find it in c:\wamp\bin\php(your php version)

If you use xamp you will find it C:\xampp\php

Comment: took me over half an hour to get this set up!! Should only have been a few minutes, most of it just telling PHPStorm where it was, not guessing WTF it wants. I read all the pages on their website, so sad that I had to get the answer from a MS Paint screenshot (But more helpful than their 100s of lines of words)

Comment: How about installing `php-cgi`?

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get install php-cgi
```

Maybe will help too.

Comment: The OP told us at the beginning of their post that they are running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 7):

if you install wamp server or any other local server in your pc... as i showed in below photos you can set the default localhost to wamp server

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After running the PHP site in the browser and getting the `502 bad gateway` error, when you switch back to PHPStorm you should see the following message:

[image: PHP Interpreter is not configured]

You must have PHP installed on your machine. To do that, you can follow the [PHP installation on Windows manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) or if you have [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) installed, just type

```
choco install php
```

Then, click the `configure PHP Interpreter` link or go to `File / Settings / PHP` and choose the PHP installation for the current project. You may also want to go to `File / Default Settings / PHP`  and do the same so that new project benefit from these settings as well.

Note that PHPStorm recognizes the PHP version but does not automatically choose the according language level. Maybe that's by intention for backward-compatible projects.

Answer (score 1):

go to phpstorm>setting>php
onthe right side (assuming you have installed wamp 5.5) choose the php version 5.5 then click the browsing buttion to choose interpreter and then choose the route (assuming you have instaled Wamp on c:/wamp) "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12" then give a name and apply ,, choose the same route on the interpreter window and add the route , now it should work fine , you can check the video on "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=953mNQ5KuBI"

Answer (score 1):

[image: SETTINGS->PHP->Interpreter]

You must select interpreter for your PHP storm to run build-in webserver.

Go to Settings->PHP->Interpreter and select one you have. If you don't have, go and download latest PHP interpreter, then come back to phpstorm menu and add Interpreter as shown at picture above.

Comment: Do you have a link for the PHP interpreter download?

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar problem when attempting to run on a different localhost on my computer.

One easy work around I found was by editing your run/debug configurations.

Before you do this, save a simple batch file to where ever you'd like on your hard drive and name it 'init.bat'.(eg. mine is 'C:\wamp64\www\myhost\init.bat'). Inside this batch file use this code to open your desired website:

```
start "" http://localhost/appname/trunk/public/
```

So head over to the run/debug configurations and then choose the php script you want to run. For example mine was called "index.php". When there, at the bottom of the window there should be a section that says, "Before launch: External tool, Activate tool window".

Click 'Run external tool' and from there add your batch file location into the program box.

Now every time you press the green play button, it will open up a the desired website in your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you see "PHP interpreter is not configure " warning when you run your projects in phpstrom, do what Mina Fawzy explains in above. 
But if you want change the port number, you should go to 
File > Settings > Build, execution and deployment > debuger

and in right site and below of built-in server change your port number. the default port number that wamp uses (if you don't change it manually), is 8080.

Answer (score 0):

It’s just happened to me. To overcome it, you can follow the steps in the below picture.

[image]