# PhpStorm don't upload JPG & GIF files

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp, phpstorm

I have some problems with PhpStorm server. When I try to upload image file with PhpStorm server (like: `http://localhost:63342/MySite`) it don't upload only jpeg and gif files, png files can be uploaded.

When file is not uploaded, the server says "502 bad gateway"  so I must shut down PhpStorm and restart it again...

But when I use XAMPP server it's all OK the files are uploaded perfectly....
So I don't get where is the problem in PhpStorm.

---

**P.S.** I use php 5.6.14. Also this problem appears in all computers not only on my pc (just you to know...)

---

**P.P.S.** I found out that the problem is in file size and not in file type.

For example I have 2 jpg files and 2 png files, one jpg and png are less than 50k and the aver two files (jpg, png) are more than 50k, so the one that is less than 50k the PhpStorm will upload but the avers more than 50k would not...

I have changed php.ini file and set upload and post max sizes to 100M but nothing happens!!! PhpStorm crashes every time I upload more than 50k files...

Dose anyone has any solution to this paranoic problem?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896638/how-to-setup-built-in-webserver-in-phpstorm

Comment: No it can't because i haves this a lot of times this link, i am setting server pretty correctly, the problem exists only when i want to upload image files with jpeg and gif extension

Comment: what server do you use ? Local or remote ? What kind of technology project ?

Comment: please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317 - looks related

Comment: "darkomen" i use Xampp server with apache port 80...
"Lena" yes it looks similar problem but it doesn't gives any solution :-(

Answer (score 1):

As @Lena has already stated: it's an issue in PhpStorm's built-in web server (handling POST requests in general). There is nothing you can do right now to bypass it (unless you use previous PhpStorm version .. or use proper Apache/nginx/IIS/whatever).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.