# Intermittent 502 error with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am trying to follow the PhpStorm "Create and Run Your First PHP Project" [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/create-and-run-your-first-php-project.html?search=first%20ph). Yes that new. :)

I believe I have followed their advice and the answer from a similar StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896638/how-to-setup-built-in-webserver-in-phpstorm) on "how to setup built-in web server in PhpStorm", but I keep get intermittent 502 errors.

I run the very simple `echo phpinfo();` program and sometimes I get 502 instead of the `phpinfo` listing.

The link is `http://localhost:63342/MyFirstPhpProject/MyFile.php`. Simply refreshing the page will sometimes give the phpinfo result and other times the 502 bad gateway result. Help. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Your PhpStorm version exactly (build number) -- `Help | About`. Your description suggests that you have an older PhpStorm as in latest version https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18171 should be fixed. In any case: I would still recommend to use proper web server (e.g. Apache or IIS) as currently built-in web server has issues with POST requests (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317 )

Comment: Other useful link for new users: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: 10.0.2 Build #PS-143.1184
I am using the apache server from an XAMPP install.

Comment: So .. if you have XAMPP .. why do you still want to use PhpStorm's own built-in web server? (note that PHP's web server is a different thing). Maybe you want to use XAMPP instead?

Comment: I am using the PHP interpreter from XAMPP.

Comment: Makes no difference here -- you need to use Apache from XAMPP as your web server -- that's what I was trying to say.