# echo does not work in Curl in PhpStorm

Tags: php, curl, phpstorm

I can not show output of curl.I use phpstorm with Xampp and echo dose not work. output in Browser in

> 502 Bad Gateway

```
<?php
$execution_time_limit = 25000;
set_time_limit($execution_time_limit);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


    $url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
    $data = getPage($url);
    echo $data;


function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 5555500);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explicitly compose a question as well as elaborate on "echo does not work". Is there an error message?

Comment: I do that my dear

Comment: your code works properly, just tested it on my machine.

Comment: but it dosent work for me..in phpstorm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to setup built-in webserver in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896638/how-to-setup-built-in-webserver-in-phpstorm)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896638/how-to-setup-built-in-webserver-in-phpstorm

Comment: my PHP interpreter in Ok. but in phpstorm it dosent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first got to:

> C:\xampp

and do that:

> - Just Run "xampp-control.exe" as administrator
> - and stop apache service action port.
> - and tick this(in snapshot) check box it will ask for install as service just install it
> - then click start

[image]

Integrating XAMPP with the IDE:

1. Let's start by registering the PHP executable from XAMPP in PhpStorm. When in a PHP project, we can do this using the File | Settings menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on Mac), navigating to the Project Settings | PHP.

[image]

2. With IntelliJ IDEA and PhpStorm, we can have several separate PHP interpreters registered in the IDE, depending on the PHP version and/or PHP configuration needed for the project. All currently registered installations of PHP interpreters are displayed in the Interpreter drop-down list:
   [image]

We can add the one we've installed with XAMPP by clicking the Browse button (…). This will bring up the Interpreters dialog box.
[image]